# Is there a common way to test complex functions with NUnit?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, nunit

is there a common way to test complex functions with several parameters with NUnit? I think it is very hard or impossible to test every condition.

I'm afraid the combination of parameters that isn't expected in the function is also not expected in the test.

So the expected condition will not fail but the unexpected.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This shouldn't be hard to test at all. If it is, the method isn't designed for testability, and that is a code smell that tells you that you need to refactor it.

I tend to write tests in these cases as follows (others may have better suggestions):

1. Does it work as intended when all appropriate parameters are passed?
2. Does it throw expected exceptions when I think it should? (ArgumentNullException, etc.)
3. For each parameter, what happens when I pass null, the minimum and the maximum. (This can be very extensive, depending on the number of arguments.)

If your method takes a lot of parameters, consider refactoring it to take an object with the information on it, so that you can encapsulate the rules for it in the object, and pass the object to the method.

Comment: Amen. If it's too hard to test, it's probably too hard to understand in the first place.

Comment: I'm joining the choir in the Church of Testability :-) If your function has a lot of of parameters, that forms a complex grid of conditions, odds are that you can split the code up in several different objects - each handling a single responsibility.

Answer (score 2):

For data-driven tests in NUnit, there is `[TestCase]` [attribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.5.9). Unit tests usually dont't test every possible scenario. They just test representative set of inputs, which have good coverage of what the SUT does on various inputs. Just pick some characteristic inputs, and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is the kind of thing you are looking for, but there is an automated unit test generator that was created by Microsoft research called [PEX](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/).

> Pex automatically generates test suites with high code coverage. Right from the Visual Studio code editor, Pex finds interesting input-output values of your methods, which you can save as a small test suite with high code coverage. Microsoft Pex is a Visual Studio add-in for testing .NET Framework applications.

Comment: The problem with automated tests is that quite often it's hard to define the expected result of the function for a more general case in a way that doesn't amount to reimplementing that very function. So you're left with just checking if the post conditions of the function hold.

Comment: This is a good tool for basic tests. But complex functions that e.g. requieres (dictionary)-keys, filepaths and other input like this fail.

Answer (score 1):

Use **RowTest** similar question can be found at

[C#, NUnit Assert in a Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004905/c-nunit-assert-in-a-loop)

have a look at @"Sam Holder" reply, I copied the code from it, with few tweaks.

```
[TestFixture] 
    public class TestExample 
    {      

    [RowTest]      
    [Row( 1)]      
    [Row( 2)]      
    [Row( 3)]      
    [Row( 4)]      

    public void TestMethodExample(int value)      
    {           
              ...
              ...
              ...
              Assert.IsTrue("some condition ..");
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mike Hofer, that the question indicates a code smell.

Nevertheless, [NUnit has a Combinatorial attribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=combinatorial&r=2.5) that might help you, if you're not refactoring/redesigning.