# C# NUnit using TestCaseSource results in NullPointer

Tags: c#, nunit

I have the following class which is a TestFixture which has one test and a TestCaseSource that produces my TestCases. My test case actually contain both the actual result and the expected result which is wrapped in an Object called TestCaseEntity

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class MyTest
    {
        static Client client;
        static List<string> userIds = new List<string>();

        [TestFixtureSetUp]
        public void Init()
        {
            // Set up a client
            client = new Client("server address"); // a HTTP client

            // populate a List of userIds from a local text test file
            userIds.Add(GetAllIdsFromTxtFile());
        }

        [Test, TestCaseSource(typeof(MyTestCaseEntityFactory), "MyTestCases")]
        public void CheckExpectations(TestCaseEntity testCaseEntity)
        {
            if (!testCaseEntity.IsIdentical)
            {
                Log.Error("Log some shit");
                Assert.Fail("fail assertions");
            }
        }

        public class MyTestCaseEntityFactory
        {
            public static IEnumerable<TestCaseEntity> MyTestCases
            {
                get
                {
                    foreach (string id in userIds)
                    {
                        // use the client and get the results, construct the new TestCaseEntity(...) and return;
                        yield return new TestCaseEntity("actualValue", "expectedValue resulting from the server call");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my Test, I get the following error which is unfortunately not very helpful!

```
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Any suggestions on what I might have done wrong?

Comment: Can you look at the exception stack trace and the failed line number? It is usually much more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You foreach over `allSalesDEDealIds` but you seem to have not included it in your code example. It might be that this is the `NullRefException`in your code?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, but that is definitely not the problem. I can see that the init method is being executed successfully!

Comment: the allSalesDEDealIds method is called well before the init method, so you need to do all the logic to get your ids inside that method, i.e. userIds.Add(GetAllIdsFromTxtFile()); must be called inside the allSalesDEDealIds method